# How can you validate a pop sequence without being given a push sequence?

Tags: javascript, stack, logic

Assume that numbers from 0 to N are being pushed in sequence onto a stack. At any point, numbers may be popped from the stack and any time a number is popped it is printed to the screen. Your task is to receive a sequence of numbers and validate whether that sequence could be the result of this procedure. Here are some examples:

Example 1:

```
Input: 0 1 2 3
Output: True

Explanation:  
push 0  
pop => print 0  
push 1  
pop => print 1  
push 2  
pop => print 2  
push 3  
pop => print 3
```

Example 2:

```
Input: 0 3 1 2
Output: False    

Explanation:
push 0  
pop => print 0  
push 1  
push 2  
push 3  
pop => print 3

The next number in the sequence is 1, which can't have been popped because
2 is still on the stack, so this sequence is invalid.
```

How could you write code to solve this problem? You have no access to the stack itself, or to a push sequence. You only know that numbers are pushed onto the stack in ascending order from 0 to N, but they can be popped at any time. I feel like the answer is right on the tip of my tongue but I am completely stumped. I'm struggling to come up with a rule that an input would need to follow in order to be considered valid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not my homework.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is off-topic, seeing as it's a programming question. This isn't a homework problem either it's just something I'd like help with.

Comment: Are we discussing the typical implementations of `push` and `pop`? If so what does the printing to screen have to do with anything? In your second example, how can you `pop` 1 before you `push` it. That first `pop` should have removed 0. If the numbers were put in in sequence, and they are now non-sequential, they weren't produced by this method, or am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, I mistyped my second example. I just edited it so that it's accurate now. You're right, the first pop removes zero. Printing to the screen doesn't really have anything to do with the problem, it's just a way to justify how we're getting this sequence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's homework.

Comment: For that matter, the comment in the second example is incorrect:  `print 3` *is* correct because it is the thing that has most recently been pushed.  The comment implies that the data structure is a FIFO *queue* not a LIFO *stack.*   Your teacher needs to fix his **homework problem.**

Comment: @MikeRobinson It seems more like a coding challenge than homework.

Comment: It is a coding challenge, not homework.

Comment: Every time you pop, it will be either higher than the last number you popped, or the highest number less than all the popped numbers. So after 0 3, the next number has to be either > 3 or 2. After 0 3 4 2, the next number has to be either > 4 or 1.